# Need help writing function ticker

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to write a function `ticker()` that will open a file read it and ask the user to input a company name. When the user inputs the company name it will return the ticker symbol of that company.

Also a data file is given, which is formatted in this way:

```
Name of Company #1
Ticker Symbol of Company #1
Name of Company #2
Ticker Symbol of Company #2
...
```

The view that I need is something like this:

```
ticker('test.txt')
Enter Company Name: YAHOO
Ticker: YHOO
```

My current code is:

```
def ticker(x):
    d = {}
    infile = open(x,'r')
    content = infile.readlines()
    for line in (x):
        file = line.split('\n')
```

But now I'm completely lost as how to compute this.

Comment: What's the format of the file that you're reading in?

Comment: please fix indentation of your code

Comment: How would you `for line in (x)` expect to work?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the format of the file you're reading in is, but the following code will read in the file and break it up into non-blank lines.

```
def ticker(filename):
    lines = open(filename).read().split('\n')
    lines = [x in lines if x]
```

Answer (score 0):

Either change your fileformat, or try this:

```
ticker = {}
for company, ticker in (x):
    ticker[company] = ticker
```

This will give you a [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), which can ba accessed in a manner like `dictionary[key]` and return its value. I am sure if you google for getting user input you can get this to work. Maybe apply a case conversion, so that the capitalization of the user input does not matter.

If this does not take you far enough consider trying harder/hiring a consultant or asking questions that show that you acctually put effort into it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure about the format of your data file, you can use code bellow, But always remember that working with files without handling possible exceptions is not a good idea.

```
def ticker(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        lines = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
        return dict(zip(lines[::2], lines[1::2]))

data = ticker('test')
name = raw_input('Enter Company Name: ')
print 'Ticker:', data.get(name.strip(), 'Not Found!')
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a very raw and simple implementation, you can improve it.

```
def ticker(filename):
    name = raw_input("Enter Company Name:")
    f = open(filename, "r")
    l = f.readline()
    ticker = ''
    while l:
        if l.strip() == name:
            ticker = f.readline().strip()
            break
        else:
            l = f.readline()
    if ticker:
        print "Ticker: %s" % ticker
    else:
        print "Ticker not found!"

ticker("1.txt")
```